# How to sort multiple text files by a specific recorded value inside the text files?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to read a specific result That has been inputted inside the text file. This value being "Total Cost" which has been implemented inside the numerous text files. I want to create a button that can read the value inside the text files itself which will than sort the text files with the greatest total cost at the top than the lowest value at the bottom.
(C#)

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example are the text files in the same directory? Is this "Total Cost" value the only data in the text files? If it's not is there a followed standard in each file for this value? For example "_some words_ Total Cost=15 _some more words_"

Comment: Its 1 of 8 inputted values.
Total cost=_____